# Ruby on Rails Bi-directional associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to achieve the following in my ruby on rails application. This is also my database layout and the model names.
[image: Illustation]

However, this isnt really working out for me.

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :follows
    has_many :users, :through => :follows
end
```

Follow model:

```
class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :follow_user_id
end
```

I use this to debug:

```
<% current_user.follows.each do |x| %>
    <%= debug x.user %>
<% end %>
```

[image: Debug]

I have no idea how to do this the other way around and I'm not even sure if I'm doing this right. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want an "is_followed_by" relationship?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397920/relationship-like-twitter-followers-followed-in-activerecord or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762919/ruby-on-rails-has-many-through-self-referential-following-follower-relationships

Comment: Just looked it up and yes, thats what I'm looking for.

Comment: The rails tutorial also has a nice explanation of how to do this. https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-the_relationship_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, you just haven't completed the associations.  First, note that User is connected twice to Follow - once in each direction.

```
rails g model User email:string name:string
rails g model Follow user:references follow_user:references
```

Then:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :followers, through: :follows

  has_many :followings, class_name: 'Follow', foreign_key: :follow_user_id, inverse_of: :follower
  has_many :users_i_follow, through: :followings, source: :user
end

class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :follows
  belongs_to :follower, inverse_of: :followers, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :follow_user_id
end
```

Now, for a user you have two associations that you'll probably mostly use: "followers" and "users_i_follow".

```
mdchaney$ bundle exec rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.5)
2.1.1 :001 > u = User.create(:email => 'test@comor.net', :name => 'Leader Guy')
 => #<User id: 1, email: "test@comor.net", name: "Leader Guy", created_at: "2014-09-26 18:48:52", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:48:52"> 

2.1.1 :002 > u2 = User.create(:email => 'follower@comor.net', :name => 'Follower Guy')
 => #<User id: 2, email: "follower@comor.net", name: "Follower Guy", created_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:13", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:13"> 

2.1.1 :003 > u3 = User.create(:email => 'follower3@comor.net', :name => 'Follower Guy, III')
 => #<User id: 3, email: "follower3@comor.net", name: "Follower Guy, III", created_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:25", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:25"> 

2.1.1 :004 > u.followers
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 

2.1.1 :005 > Follow.create(:user => u, :follower => u2)
 => #<Follow id: 1, user_id: 1, follow_user_id: 2, created_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:12", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:12"> 

2.1.1 :006 > Follow.create(:user => u, :follower => u3)
 => #<Follow id: 2, user_id: 1, follow_user_id: 3, created_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:14", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:14"> 

2.1.1 :007 > u = User.find(1)
 => #<User id: 1, email: "test@comor.net", name: "Leader Guy", created_at: "2014-09-26 18:48:52", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:48:52"> 

2.1.1 :008 > u.followers
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 2, email: "follower@comor.net", name: "Follower Guy", created_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:13", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:13">, #<User id: 3, email: "follower3@comor.net", name: "Follower Guy, III", created_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:25", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:25">]> 

2.1.1 :009 > u.follows
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Follow id: 1, user_id: 1, follow_user_id: 2, created_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:12", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:12">, #<Follow id: 2, user_id: 1, follow_user_id: 3, created_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:14", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:14">]> 

2.1.1 :010 > u2 = User.find(2)
 => #<User id: 2, email: "follower@comor.net", name: "Follower Guy", created_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:13", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:49:13"> 

2.1.1 :011 > u2.followers
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 

2.1.1 :012 > u2.follows
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 

2.1.1 :013 > u2.followings
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Follow id: 1, user_id: 1, follow_user_id: 2, created_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:12", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:50:12">]>

2.1.1 :014 > u2.users_i_follow
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 1, email: "test@comor.net", name: "Leader Guy", created_at: "2014-09-26 18:48:52", updated_at: "2014-09-26 18:48:52">]>
```

Answer (score 0):

This also can be done with a single `has_many :through` association. See [the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61904089/535406).

It's for the `friends / friendships` problem but it's basically identical to the `followers / follows` problem.