# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have  this function inside user model

```
def send_request(user_id)
    unless Friendship.exists?(self.id,user_id) 
      Friendship.create(sender_id:self.id, receiver_id:user_id)
    end
  end
```

In the rails console `u1 = User.find(1)`
then  `u1.send_request(2)`
I see ArgumentError (`wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)` What is the meaning of expected 0..1? and why it is given 2?

Comment: I'm guessing `Friendship.exists?(self.id,user_id)` is giving the error. Unless you have clobbered [`ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#exists?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) its defined as `exists?(conditions = :none)`. That gives an arity of `0..1` as it has one argument with a default value. Of course we can't really know without a proper stack trace. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: This is a possible duplicate (at least in spirit) of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244283/how-to-model-a-mutual-friendship-in-rails

Comment: I used Rails console this is why I didn't know which line giving this error.
I changed the function name from exists? to requested_before  so It does not get confused with the built-in function of rails
so It works now Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exists? method is defined as:

```
def exists?(conditions = :none)
  ...
end
```

It means, `conditions` is the only argument the method is expecting to receive, and you have passed this when invoking it `self.id, user_id`, two arguments, `self.id` and `user_id`.

To fix the problem you have to decide which value you're going to use to validate if the Friendship record exists or not in your database. But whatever it is, it should be either `self.id`, `user_id` or any other, but just one.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this, doing the check after filtering.

```rb
if Friendship.where(sender_id: self.id, receiver_id: user_id).exists?
```

but then again you might just as well use

```rb
Friendship.find_or_create_by(sender_id: self.id, receiver_id: user_id)
```

Comment: You can use the `where` argument on `exists?`, it remains as a single hash argument.

Comment: Correct, for some reason I have always preferred this way though.